# NodeJs Convert string to BSON object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoid, bson

How i can convert string (_id) to BSON object?

As a driver I'm using [monk](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monk [defines the `id` and `oid` (alias) methods](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk#casting) for casting to `ObjectID`:

```
users.id() // returns new generated ObjectID
users.id('hexstring') // returns ObjectId
users.id(obj) // returns ObjectId
```

Though it seems capable of [working with the string](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk#by-id) as well:

```
users.findById('hex representation', function(err, doc){});
users.findById(oid, function(err, doc){});
```

Answer (score -4):

convert to json then to bson I think

Comment: :) OK! How convert JSON to BSON?

Comment: @Pablo208 You need to provide more information that this for this answer to have much value. (As it is, it's pretty much a hint, rather than an answer.)

Comment: @middaparka apologies I was running out of work and should have elaborate  Jonathan Lonowski answer  works so I'll leave it at that.